# What do margin:5px 0; and margin:5px 0 0; mean?

Tags: css

Does `margin:5px 0;` mean `margin:5px 0 0 0;` or `margin:5px 0 5px 0;`?

Does `margin:5px 0 0;` mean `margin:5px 0 0 0;`?

Same for padding of course.

Also, is it consistent across all browsers (including IE6)?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

According to [Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html):

> - If there is only one value, it applies
>     to all sides.
> - If there are two values,
>     the **top** and **bottom** margins are set to
>     the first value and the **right** and **left**
>     margins are set to the second.
> - If
>     there are three values, the **top** is set
>     to the first value, the **left** and **right**
>     are set to the second, and the **bottom**
>     is set to the third.
> - If there are four
>     values, they apply to the **top**, **right**,
>     **bottom**, and **left**, respectively.

```
body { margin: 2em }         /* all margins set to 2em */
body { margin: 1em 2em }     /* top & bottom = 1em, right & left = 2em */
body { margin: 1em 2em 3em } /* top=1em, right=2em, bottom=3em, left=2em */
```

This is defined by the CSS standard, so it should be consistent across all browsers that implements CSS correctly. For browser compatibilities, check out blooberry's [CSS Support History](http://blooberry.com/indexdot/css/properties/margin/margin.htm) and [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html). According to blooberry, `margin` was first implemented in IE3, so IE6 should be fine.

Comment: Any idea of every browser follows this?

Comment: Umm, not sure if "standard" means all browsers...I wish though.

Comment: margin has always been implemented this way. This should work for all browsers that's still around.

Answer (score 12):

For margin and padding, you can specify one, two, three, or four whitespace-separated values:

1. One value: **All four sides** use that value.
2. Two values: **top/bottom** get the first value; **left/right** get the second
3. Three values: **top** gets the first, **left/right** get the second, **bottom** gets the third
4. Four values: Top, right, bottom, left (i.e. **clockwise from noon**) get each value

Answer (score 2):

`margin: 5px 0;` means `margin: 5px 0 5px 0;`

`margin: 5px 0 0;` means `margin: 5px 0 0 0;`

All browsers follow this, including IE 6.